# Android Identify listView using onItemClick listener

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I have two `ListViews` in my activity that uses same `OnItemClickListener`. Is there any way to identify which `ListViews` element I am pressing now? I have used this code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position,
        long id) {


    if (view.getId() == R.id.listDictionary) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordActivity.class);
    DictionaryListElement ele = (DictionaryListElement) dictionaryList
            .getAdapter().getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("word", ele.getWord());

    startActivity(intent);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.listFavourites) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordActivity.class);
        String ele = (String)favouritesList.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("word", ele);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

But it is not working. I think it is getting id of each pressed element not `ListViews`

Comment: what is wrong in the above code?

Comment: Try using list view id not the view.getId()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ID of `ListView` (here `ListView` is passed as `AdapterView` to `onItemClick()`), not the ID of `View` as this `View` is a `ListView` item.

```
if(list.getId() == R.id.listDictionary) {
    // item in dictionary list is clicked
} else if (list.getId() == R.id.listFavourites) {
   // item in favourite list is clicked
}
```

Comment: I understand that the question was asking, why the code is not working, and your answer is totally correct, but I don't understand why one would encourage to continue using such a messy logic.

Comment: @AlexanderGavrilov why you feel this code is messy? but for me, It is a code reusability and minimal code and proper documented code is never messy...

Comment: I have noticed list prameter only now LOL.

Comment: Because ideally method should do one thing only (there are real-life exceptions, but not this one). Also, properly documented code - is a self documented code, which is not achievable with such constructions.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need the same listener if you distinguish logic with ifs? Create separate listeners for each view. It would be cleaner code and should work as well.

```
// dictionary listener
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordActivity.class);
    DictionaryListElement ele = (DictionaryListElement) dictionaryList
            .getAdapter().getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("word", ele.getWord());

    startActivity(intent);
}

// favorites listener
     @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordActivity.class);
            String ele = (String)favouritesList.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            intent.putExtra("word", ele);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. My thoughts became as complicated as Android code

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(list.getId()){
case R.id.listDictionary: 
//listDictionary related action here
break;

case R.id.listFavourites:  
// listFavourites related action here
break;

default:
  break;
}
```